# Vidyo Web using Javascript - How to render local camera to more than one view?

Tags: vidyo

I tried calling AssignViewToLocalCamera with different view Ids in which the first first invoke is working and the subsequent calls are not.

```
//working
_vidyoConnector.AssignViewToLocalCamera({
            viewId: "div1",
            localCamera: _localCamera,
            displayCropped: false,
            allowZoom: false
        });
// not working
    vidyoConnector.AssignViewToLocalCamera({
            viewId: "div2",
            localCamera: _localCamera,
            displayCropped: false,
            allowZoom: false
        })
// not working
        vidyoConnector.AssignViewToLocalCamera({
                viewId: "div3",
                localCamera: _localCamera,
                displayCropped: false,
                allowZoom: false
            })
```

Please show some light here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the same video stream to multiple renderer div is not supported by vidyo.io.